# Timeout in shellscript

Tags: shell

I want to put timeout in my shell script for process to be done within that,for example if I want to scp one file, if that file doesn't transfered within timeout through an error, if success echo a success message, how to put timeout ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`timeout(1)`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/timeout). Much better than a homebrew solution which you'll have to write, debug and maintain.

Comment: Damn it, I knew I there was a more elegant solution :D I guess I learned a valuable lesson here, even though a little exercise in shell scripting is never a bad thing!

Comment: As an exercise, definitely not. As development time, I don't think it is. It usually results in flaky code that requires time and effort to maintain.

Comment: Totally agreed, hence my vote up for your answer. I cannot believe I didn't know about thuis builtin command btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for example:

```
command &    # start a new process in background
pid=$(pidof command | cut -f1 -d' ')    # save pid of started process
sleep(timeout_value)    # set timeout value to match your desired time to process
pids=$(pidof command)    # get all pids of running processes of this command
if [[ $(grep "$pid" "$pids") ]]; then    # if started process still running
    echo "error"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

Change the word command to match your actual command. I'm not sure if this will work with a pipeline, I'll test it out in a minute and get back to you.

For a pipeline command you could do the following (provided you're executing using bash):

```
(command | other_command | ...) &
pid=$(pidof bash | cut -f1 -d' ')    # save pid of started process
sleep(timeout_value)    # set timeout value to match your desired time to process
pids=$(pidof bash)    # get all pids of running bash processes
if [[ $(grep "$pid" "$pids") ]]; then    # if started process still running 
    echo "error"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

**Problem**

Note that there are better answers out there as this script will always wait out the entire timeout. Which might not be what you desire.

**Possible solution**

A possible solution is to sleep multiple times, something like this:

```
for i in $(seq 1..100); do
    sleep(timeout/100)  # sample the timeout interval
    pids=$(pidof bash)
    if [[ $(grep -v "$pid" "$pids") ]]; then   # if process no longer running
        echo "succes" && exit 0     # process completed, success!
    elif [[ $i -eq 100 ]]; then
        echo "error"    # at the end of our timeout
    fi
done
```

Note: change the value 100 if your timeout is really long, try to optimize it so timeout per iteration is not too long.